# How to authenticate facebook in a subclass of Service in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator

I am using `facebook.authorize(activity,new Dialog(...))` in

```
public class BirthdayActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}
```

It works perfectly here, but when I do the same in

```
public class StartBirthdayApplication extends Service {
    ...
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
...
}
```

I get the error

> Key message expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.The default value `<null>`was returned.
>   Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

just pass access token in request.
working correct.